# Bind a property on data context to another object contained within the data context

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding

Consider the scenario shown below

```
class MyViewModel
{
    public bool IsSelected {get;set;}
}

class SomeClass
{
    public bool IsSelected {get;set;}
    public object Data {get;}
}

<DataTemplate x:Key="ItemTemplate>
    <Image ... />
</DataTemplate>

<SomeControl ItemsSource={Binding MyViewModels}"
             ItemTemplate={StaticResource ItemTemplate}" />
```

The classes `SomeControl` and `SomeClass` are third party classes which I cannot modify. Internally, `SomeControl` creates instances of `SomeClass` and assigns my view model to its `Data` property. So, the data context of my ItemTemplate is `SomeClass`

I want to bind the `IsSelected` property on `SomeClass` to the `IsSelected` property of `MyViewModel`. How do I do that?

Comment: Where do you store an instance of MyViewModel? Besides, if it's not set as DataContext, it's not really a ViewModel...

Comment: As I already said, the instance of MyViewModel is assigned to the Data property of Some Class. And its out of my control, its the third part control that does that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I would consider ditching a third-party control that does something so at odds with how the `ItemsControl` normally works. Your data context should be your view model. Period.

That said, you should be able to work around it if the item container is a `SomeClass` like this:

```
<SomeControl ...>
    <SomeControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="SomeClass">
            <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding Data.IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
        </Style>
    </SomeControl.ItemContainerStyle>
</SomeControl>
```